# CXX0017error symbol not found for dllimport variables

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, shared-memory

I have two different DLLs and via dllimport/export I am able to share some variables betweens the two dlls! My code runs, but while debugging , when I add those imported variables to the watch window, it says: CXX0017error symbol "MyVariable" not found. The other variables which are not imported are fine. 
Any clue what is going wrong? 
Do I need to enable something in VISUAL STUDIO? Or import some outfile from the DLL were the shared variables are declared?
Thx